# Unable to mount specific paths as volumes

Tags: docker, boot2docker

If I run the following command:

```
$ docker run --rm --volume $(pwd)/frontend/vhost.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf --interactive --tty  mycontainer -c bash
```

I get an error:

```
Timestamp: 2015-11-30 15:47:43.468719608 +0000 UTC
Code: Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 270b7bbd30a96fbe98c0992e80dd66f0947ea0868f8a2fc42fe0904267a6003b: [8] System error: not a directory
```

However if I copy the mount point contents to another random folder name, the error disappears, as per:

```
$ cp -r frontend frontend3
$ docker run --rm --volume $(pwd)/frontend3/vhost.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf --interactive --tty  mycontainer -c bash
root@318cd89c6cc5:/#
```

Strangely I seem to have not only corrupted the `frontend/` path, but also `frontend2`:

```
$ cp -r frontend frontend2
$ docker run --rm --volume $(pwd)/frontend2/vhost.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf --interactive --tty  mycontainer -c bash
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container b6792a443afff369a827e0ab0058e952e028ead9dfcad5204050bc366754e370: [8] System error: not a directory
```

I'm running docker-machine / boot2docker on OSX via VirtualBox:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.8.3
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   f4bf5c7
 Built:        Mon Oct 12 18:01:15 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.8.3
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   f4bf5c7
 Built:        Mon Oct 12 18:01:15 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

$ docker-machine -v
docker-machine version 0.4.1 (e2c88d6)
```

I've run a number of projects with similar or more complex volume mounts over the last 6 months on this box, and this is the first time I've encountered such an anomaly.

Comment: Fixed this by upgrading Docker and Docker-Machine/Boot2Docker ISO to 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by upgrading Docker and Docker-Machine/Boot2Docker ISO to 1.9.1